# Probability of union of mutually independent sets

Tags: probability

> A sequence $\{A_k: k\geq 1\}$ is a mutually independent sets with $P(A_k)=1/(k+1)$ for $k=1,2,3,\cdots,n$, compute $P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k)$.

To compute $P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k)$, the way I get is to apply
$P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(A_k)-\sum_{j<k}P(A_j\bigcap A_k)+\cdots$ But it seems too complicated. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**.

- $P\Bigl(\bigcup A_k\Bigr)=1-P\Bigl(\bigcap \overline{A_k}\Bigr)$;
- if the sets $A_k$ are mutually independent, so are the sets $\overline{A_k}$.

Comment: Furthermore, In order to avoid unnecessary arithmetic calculations, it is of the utmost importance that the penultimate equation in the calculation  _not_ be expressed as $$1 - [1-P(A_1)]\cdots[1-P(A_n)]$$ and multiplied out to get $$P(A_1) + \cdots +P(A_n) - [P(A_1A_2) + P(A_1)P(A_3) + \cdots + P(A_{n-1}P(A_n)] + \cdots $$ which is the answer via the principle of inclusion and exclusion and requires too much computation. Instead, $n$ subtractions $1-P(A_k)$, $n-1$ multiplications, and one final subtraction is the way tp go.